# View width not changed after scale ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, objectanimator

Shouldn't the width change after I animate the scaleX property? I noticed that the clickable area shrinks when I reduce the views width, so I guess the width must be adapted. But when I call view.getWidth() I still get the initial value.

```
        Log.d(TAG, "" + getWidth()); //Initial value
        setPivotX(getWidth() / 2);
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, View.SCALE_X, 1.0f, 0.8f);
        animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1));
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Log.d(TAG, "" + getWidth()); //Initial value :(
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animator.start();
```

Comment: I know it was a long time ago, but did you solve the issue? If yes, could you give some advices? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that View animations change these properties (size, boundaries or visibility). You have to do this on your own, at the end of the animation.

From this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

> Note: Regardless of how your animation may move or resize, the bounds
>   of the View that holds your animation will not automatically adjust to
>   accommodate it. Even so, the animation will still be drawn beyond the
>   bounds of its View and will not be clipped. However, clipping will
>   occur if the animation exceeds the bounds of the parent View.

Comment: Well, that's the case for View animations. My question was about property animations that are available since API lvl 11 or in my example even 14. The advantage should be that you don't have to deal with the fillAfter stuff after your animation has finished. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no chance to animate width or height with VPA,
try this by value-property-animator compat:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435848/1835650